# How to change the background color of menubar of Tkinter Widget

Tags: python, tkinter, winapi, tkinter-menu

I'm trying to change the background color of the menubar that I made using the Tkinter widget, I changed the background color of the title-bar thanks to a solution that I came across on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70724666/edit) even tho it wasn't for windows 10 but it worked in my windows 10 however it's not able to change the color of the menubar.

Here's the code including the function to change title-bar.

```
from tkinter import *
import ctypes as ct


root = Tk()

root.title("MenuBar in GUI")
root.geometry("500x500")
root.config(bg="black")


 # These attributes are not working, menubar still remains unchanged 

menubar = Menu(root, bg='black', fg='cyan', activebackground="grey",activeforeground="cyan")


filemenu = Menu(menubar, bg="black", fg="purple",activebackground="grey", activeforeground="cyan", tearoff=False)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

root.config(bg="black", menu=menubar)  # Defining the main menu

root.mainloop()
```

When i tried to customize the menubar it didn't worked as it's shown in this screenshot, Background and other colors are suppose to change but it didn't.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXD6Z.png)

Comment: Both the window titlebar and menu are controlled by the OS and not `tkinter`. Look through the Windows API for functions that can change the background colour of the menu and use `ctypes` to access those functions.

Comment: Thank you, let me give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to change the background color of the menubar that I made
> using the Tkinter widget.

Try this.

```
import tkinter as tk

 
class MenuBar(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, bd=1, relief='raised')
        self.master=master
        self.configure(background='orange', cursor='hand2')

        file = tk.Menubutton(self, text='File',
                             background='black',
                             foreground='red',
                             activeforeground='black',
                             activebackground='white'
                             )
        file_menu = tk.Menu(file,tearoff=0)
        file_menu.add_command(label='save', 
                              background='black',
                              foreground='white',
                              activeforeground='black',
                              activebackground='white'
                              )
        
        file.config(menu=file_menu)
        file.pack(side='left')

        edit = tk.Menubutton(self, text='Edit',
                             background='blue',
                             foreground='white',
                             activeforeground='black',
                             activebackground='white'
                             )
        edit_menu = tk.Menu(edit,tearoff=0)
        edit_menu.add_command(label='add',
                              background='black',
                              foreground='white',
                              activeforeground='black',
                              activebackground='white'
                              )

        edit.config(menu=edit_menu)
        edit.pack(side='left')

         

 
root = tk.Tk()
menubar = MenuBar(root)
menubar.pack(side='top', fill='x')
root.mainloop()
```

Output before:

[image]

Output after:

[image]